# Genealogy tree in Arabic/Amazigh scripts

Tags: fonts, fontspec, unicode, arabic

I am trying to build a Family tree with the genealogytree package using Arabic/Berber scripts, but the generated trees do not show the names in those scripts (it shows a question mark instead).

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{genealogypicture}[template = database portrait]
    parent {
        g[id=said1990]{
            male,
            name={سعيد},
            birth={1990}{},
            marriage={}{},
            burial={}{},
            image={},
            }
        c[id=b]{
            male,
            name={},
            birth={1992}{},
            marriage={}{},
            burial={}{},
            image={},
            }
        }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're using the arabic characters with Roman font Family. Use `name={\arabicfont سعيد}` and it works.

Comment: or write `\begin{genealogypicture}[template = database portrait,name font=\arabicfont]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I tried LianTze's solution and it's working. Now what if I want to use Tifinagh (Berber script) instead? Do you have any idea what do I need to modify in order to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a font which contain "tifinagh" script with `\newfontfamily\tifinaghfont{name_of_font}` then  insert your text with 
`{\tifinaghfont  your tifinagh text}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\tifinaghfont{Noto Sans Tifinagh}

\begin{document}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{genealogypicture}[template = database portrait,name font=\arabicfont]
    parent {
        g[id=said1990]{
            male,
            name={\tifinaghfont  ⵙⴰⵉⴷ},
            birth={1990}{},
            marriage={}{},
            burial={}{},
            image={},
            }
        c[id=b]{
            male,
            name={},
            birth={1992}{},
            marriage={}{},
            burial={}{},
            image={},
            }
        }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

[image]